# How to create multiple sites using different url in typo3 neos?

Tags: php, neoscms

i just started to use typo3 neos for my project, i heard this framework can handle multiple sites.
i found it here 
http://docs.typo3.org/neos/TYPO3NeosDocumentation/Introduction/FeatureList.html

it's stated that it have Multi Domain Support.
But i seeems cant find the documentation, so how do i do that?
i try to play around with routes but it didn't work, or it seems that i don't know what i'm doing.
is it really possible?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution here for anyone courious, sorry i can't comment because i got no reputation.

http://www.matthias-witte.net/old-content/Create%20your%20own%20site%20with%20TYPO3%20Flow%20and%20Neos%20-%20Matthias%20Witte.pdf